# Place icon inside submit button using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-form

I am trying to achieve the effect as shown in below screenshot using Bootstrap 3.

[image]

As you can see, the search button is both:

1) inside the input

2) styled with a glyphicon so as to not appear like a "button".

How can I achieve a similar effect with Bootstrap 3? I would like to place a button with a magnifying glass glyphicon at the end of a text input, however the button keeps appearing below the input as opposed to inside of it.

Comment: tried this? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A wrapper div with `position: relative;` then positioning the submit button on top using `position: absolute;`. Like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VtP5k/

**HTML**

```
<form>

    <div id="search">

        <input type="text" />
        <button type="sutmit">Search</button>

    </div>

</form>
```

**CSS**

```
#search {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
}

#search input {
    width: 194px;
}

#search button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 3px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

> In bootstrap you have to use button type submit instead of input type;
>   Both works fine! use button in bootstrap!

```css
div {
  padding: 15px;
  background: #000;
}
.btn {
  text-align: left !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
  padding: 20px 12px !important;
  width: 200px !important;
  color: #888 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
  awesomeness <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search pull-right"></span> 
</button>
  <div>
```

Or see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyCFS/936/)

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
Awesomeness <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> 
</button>
```

Comment: This is not the effect I am looking for. I am trying to have a button inside of a text input.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the button is adhering to the normal flow of html and thus appears below the first element. What you need to do is wrap both the input and search button in an div and then make the search button absolute positioning. Then you can ad some jQuery functionality on a click function to achieve an event is needs be.

```
<html>
<body>

    <div>
        <input type="text" value="test"/>
        <span id="search" class="absolute">x</span>
    </div>
  

 <style>
    .absolute {
       position:absolute;
       top:9px;
       left:115px;
             }

 </style>

 <script>
    $(document).on('click','#search',function(){
     //some functionality
    }

 </script>


</body>

</html>
```